What means this message "[emerg] host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"?
This is my docker-compose.yaml file
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        volumes_from:
            - app
    app:
        build:
            dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        

And this is my nginx config file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /app/public;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}

What I'm doing wrong?
I run 'docker compose up' but it is showing me this message:
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:8

Ok, I found the answer, I didn't write well the nginx config file cause I just clicked enter when github copilot suggested what to put.
The mistake is that 'fastcgi_pass php:9000;' needs to be: 'fastcgi_pass app:9000;' cause that is how I called my service in the docker-compose.yaml file.
So 'app' is my name for the php service, but probably many people just write the name by the technology.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
